Interop with nethost.dll fails, not sure why
I am trying to interop with nethost.dll but it keeps returning a non-zero integer which indicates failure. I am not very familiar with native interop in C# so I am having a hard time diagnosing the issue.
The interop code is below, generated using ClangSharpPInvokeGenerator:
[DllImport("runtimes/win-x64/nethost.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int get_hostfxr_path(ushort* buffer, nuint* buffer_size, get_hostfxr_parameters* parameters);

public unsafe partial struct get_hostfxr_parameters
{
    public nuint size;

    public ushort* assembly_path;

    public ushort* dotnet_root;
}

The interop code is called by the code below, based on the example provided in Microsoft's hosting guide:
ushort* ptr = stackalloc ushort[ushort.MaxValue];
nuint* size = stackalloc nuint[ushort.MaxValue / sizeof(ushort*)];
int i = nethost.get_hostfxr_path(ptr, size, null);

Once returned, the buffer passed doesn't change from the value set before calling get_hostfxr_path. The integer returns as -2147450728.
I've tried changing the PInvoke's buffer and buffer_size arguments to IntPtr. It still worked but the error code didn't change. I've also looked at interop code present in other open-source projects but I can't figure out another method for writing mine.
What exactly am I missing here? I would really appreciate the help, I'm out of my depth and flailing.

It's unclear to me why you would call this from inside a .NET app since it has to do with hosting the CLR, but aside from that ushort.MaxValue / sizeof(ushort*) looks wrong to me - I believe size should contain the number of elements that the buffer can hold, hence ushort.MaxValue in your case.

@500-InternalServerError I am not trying to host the CLR, I need a version-agnostic method for locating HostFxr for a build/dependency manager I am writing.

for a build/dependency manager - ah, makes sense.

The error you get is HostApiBufferTooSmall because you pass a buffer of invalid size. Your size argument is a pointer to an array that contains garbage. You can fix it like this:
var ptr = stackalloc ushort[ushort.MaxValue];
var size = stackalloc nuint[1];
*size = ushort.MaxValue;
var hr = get_hostfxr_path(ptr, size, null);

Or simply this:
var ptr = stackalloc ushort[ushort.MaxValue];
var size = (nuint)ushort.MaxValue;
var hr = get_hostfxr_path(ptr, &size, null);

Also, you can use ushort, but it may be easier to use .NET's natural char and string types directly, this should work too:
const int bufferSize = 2048; // or ushort.MaxValue but seems too large
var str = new string('\0', bufferSize);
var size = bufferSize / sizeof(char);
fixed (char* buffer = str)
{
    var hr = get_hostfxr_path((ushort*)buffer, (nuint*)&size, null);
    if (hr >= 0)
    {
        str = str[..(size - 1)]; // final string
    }
}


The last solution worked, the only problem is that buffer needs to be converted into ushort* for get_hostfxr_path to accept it. I have edited your answer to reflect that. Thanks!

@DuelTrimble - yes, in the last solution, I had redefined the first parameter as a char*.
